# Store output of helm command in a variable

Tags: python, kubernetes-helm, status

I am trying to store the output of my helm command in a variable in bash script and trying to echo it but it return giving an error ..syntax error in expression

Here is my code
MY_VAR=$((helm ls -A -o json))
echo ${MY_VAR}

Comment: You tagged this with "python"; if this is in the context of a Python program, I'd directly capture the output of `subprocess.run()` rather than trying to do anything complicated at the shell layer (indeed, avoid `subprocess.run(shell=True)` if at all possible).

Answer (score 0):

To execute one command after another you must add `&&` between them.
Also, you do not need double parentheses.

For example:

```
MY_VAR=$(helm ls -A -o json) && echo ${MY_VAR}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you got double brackets
Change into

```
 MY_VAR=$(helm ls -A -o json)
```

this solve the problem for me